# Redirect 301 for ?index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I've got a simple problem. I need to redirect strange URL in my client's Joomla installation.

I've got a link like `example.com/?index.php` that I need to redirect to `example.com/` in `.htaccess`.

I tried the following, but it's not working

```
Redirect 301 /?index.php /
```

Comment: Are you sure there's a question mark in there? In your url? The syntax looks strange to me. Query string should follow after the `index.php` not before it

Comment: Yes, google indexed it and i dont know source of this question mark that`s why i need to redirect it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> example.com/?index.php
> ```

In this URL, `index.php` is in the query string part of the URL. You can't use a mod_alias `Redirect` to catch this, you must use mod_rewrite.

Near the top of your `.htaccess` file (after the existing `RewriteEngine` directive) try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index\.php$
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R,L]
```

The `?` on the end of the *substitution* effectively removes the query string from the request.

This is also a temporary (302) redirect, change the `R` to `R=301` only when you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: yeah! its working now, thank you, Redirect make it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with an absolute URL as the target:

```
Redirect 301 /?index.php http://www.yourdomain.com/
```

Comment: not working, i tried with domains and without, dunno what to do :/

Comment: meybe something with RuleCond ? but in Joomla i don`t know how to construct it.

Comment: You could post the complete .htaccess file, so we can have a look at your rules/conditions.

Comment: and ? some advice ?

Comment: The `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only, not the query string, so this will never match.